# Uploading file to SFTP using SSH.NET: Cannot connect

Tags: c#, file-upload, sftp, ssh.net

I have built a console application to upload a file to a FTP server. As this FTP server only accepts SFTP protocol I am using SSH.NET open source library since there are no built in method in .NET (At less for .NET 3.5, which is the one I am using under Visual Studio 2008 Professional).

I have seen a lot of examples. I have implemented a quick test application to connect to a public SFTP server and upload a file using SFTP protocol.

I am using below public free SFTP server obtained from [here](http://www.sftp.net/public-online-sftp-servers):

```
server   : demo.wftpserver.com
user     : demo-user
password : demo-user
port     : 2222
```

And here is the code:

```
    const string host             = "demo.wftpserver.com";
    const string username         = "demo-user";
    const string password         = "demo-user";
    const string workingdirectory = "/upload";
    const string uploadfile       = @"C:\test.txt";
    const int    port             = 2222;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {                
            using (SftpClient client = new SftpClient(host, port, username, password))
            {
                {
                    client.Connect();
                    Console.WriteLine("Connected to {0}", host);

                    client.ChangeDirectory(workingdirectory);
                    Console.WriteLine("Changed directory to {0}", workingdirectory);

                    var listDirectory = client.ListDirectory(workingdirectory, null);
                    Console.WriteLine("Listing directory:");
                    foreach (var fi in listDirectory)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(" - " + fi.Name);
                    }

                    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(uploadfile, FileMode.Open))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Uploading {0} ({1:N0} bytes)", uploadfile, fileStream.Length);
                        client.BufferSize = 4 * 1024; // bypass Payload error large files
                        client.UploadFile(fileStream, Path.GetFileName(uploadfile), null);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
```

The problem is the following:

When trying to connect with the server using sentence below:

```
client.Connect();
```

I get an exception. The exception says the following:

```
"Value cannot be null. \r\nParameter name: All lists are either null or empty."

StackTrace  "   at Renci.SshNet.Session.WaitOnHandle(WaitHandle waitHandle, TimeSpan timeout)\r\n   at Renci.SshNet.Session.WaitOnHandle(WaitHandle waitHandle)\r\n   at Renci.SshNet.Session.Connect()\r\n   at Renci.SshNet.BaseClient.Connect()\r\n   at ConsoleApplication2.Program.Main(String[] args) at C:\\Users\\Win7\\Downloads\\ConsoleApplication2\\ConsoleApplication2\\Program.cs:line 61"    string
```

Also, I have tried to change the timeout as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33216301/c-sharp-renci-sshnet-sftp-connect-throwing-argumentnullexception) but without success.

However, If I try to connect to the same SFTP server using the same credentials from FileZilla client, then I can connect without problems and even upload a file.

So I do not understand what is happening. Could someone help me?

**UPDATE**:
I have found this [fix](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET/issues/113). The patch was applied in develop brank on 22 January 2017 but the last binary for download is 14th December 2016. So how can I get the binaries that includes this fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved.

I downloaded the source code from developer branch in which this bug is corrected. Then I open .NET Framework 3.5 project in Visual Studio 2015 and I build it. So I obtained the binaries, DLL for release and debug. Then I come back to my Visual Studio 2008 project and I add this reference. And I have checked that with the same code now I can connect to FTP server with same credentials.

Last binary provided in SSH.NET web does not include this bug fixed.

Answer (score -4):

I used Tamir.SharpSSH for sending file in our SFTP. Try to use this one, below code is the simplest way to send file to your sftp.

```
Sftp sftpBase = new Tamir.SharpSsh.Sftp(_sftpHost, _sftpUid, Up_decryptPass);
sftpBase.Connect(int.Parse(_sftpPort));
sftpBase.Put(Dir + filename, sftpDir);
```

Comment: SharpSSH is a dead project. Do not use it. It's website is even down, atm.

Comment: It's not dead. We're currently using it on our projects.

Comment: The last version is from 2011 and the web page has not been updated since 2007. That's what I call dead for a security related library. It cannot even support any modern ciphers.

Comment: Suggesting use of an obsolete and insecure library over a well-maintained and up-to-date library deserves the -1 => You should delete your answer to remove the -1.